# JavaScript Rails code not working in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#client-select2').select2();
   });
```

If i place the code above to application.js, it does not respond but if I place it in the _form.html.erb file, it does. Anyone know why that is?

#### views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#client-select2').select2();
   });

</script>

<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :code %>
    <%= f.association :client, collection: Client.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a Client", required: true, input_html: { id: 'client-select2' } %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### application.html.erb has

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: I think you need to state your problem better in order to get any valuable help.
Be more specific about what part that's not working.

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763031/rails-3-javascript-not-working). You may need to enclose your javascript in `jQuery` function.

Comment: @gernberg I tried to clarify my question, please check above

Comment: @kiddorails that refers to coffee script, I am not using any coffee script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason could be that select2 and/or jQuery is included after your application.js,

If for instance, if the order is:

```
//=require_self
//=require select2
//=require jquery
```

The jquery/select2 functions will not be available in application.js since application.js is included before.

Comment: I was missing require_self, oboi. Thanks

Comment: If I put the js code in assets/javascript/orders.js and add require orders in application.js would the code work? would that be the right way to do this sort of stuff?

Comment: ah it worked putting it in orders.js if I add require orders under the require self, perfect